# GeoDjango - How to present points on a map?

Tags: django, geodjango

Simple 'Example' - have millions of points within specific geography. Have everything loaded and able to see in GeoAdmin the whole 9 yards.

So. How do I show all points on a map - and base it on zoom level?  Are there any simple examples out there?

Comment: I have a similar question with a one proposal here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559431/how-to-display-data-using-openlayers-with-openstreetmap-in-geodjango

Comment: Use lefletjs to display points, it's very easy http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my GTileOverlay lass I wrote for django. It takes a queryset with lots of points, then splits them up into 256*256 squares for easy overlaying onto google maps.

[project url](http://github.com/nbv4/django-gtileoverlay)